# Creating a private network within a Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking, home-server

Creating a private network within a Network

***Total noob here***. [Asking for some Advice and Guidance and How-to]

Read on SU and found it is possible [link below]. Related to Networking.

**Situation**
So I moved to a new place and I'm in the last room where I don't get any WiFi signal from the Public Hostel network. [The Router - Huawei B310S - 4G LTE router]

**The Question**
What I'm wondering is whether it is possible to  receive Internet through an Ethernet cable from the Public one [Landlord said OK] to my spare router and create my own SSID to broadcast it out.

**Additional things I want to do**
And if it would be possible to have a Private secluded subnet because I am currently using my spare WiFi router as a mean to connect all my devices for easy sharing [media servers and such] which I do not want the other peeps on the Public network to access.

Could someone please guide me

Thank you

LINK : [Creating a private sub-network on existing shared network](https://superuser.com/questions/957634/creating-a-private-sub-network-on-existing-shared-network)

EDIT: 
[Added an Image for easy understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbNeZ.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, provided you can run the ethenet cable into the landlords AP (or router), this is entirely feasible, and a good way of doing things.    Pretty much any WIFI ethernet router would do this - although you might need to change the default LAN range from 192.168.1.x  to something (I'd suggest 10.y.x.x).

You would plug the WAN interface on your router to the LAN interface on the landlords AP (and, provided you change the LAN range on your router) it should "just work", and it will isolate your LAN from the landlords LAN meaning your devices can share media but no one else can.

Comment: Understood, will get back to you once I get the wire. Once I change the LAN range, should I enable DHCP too? All the other settings should be derived from the Landlord's Router or should it be left to the default settings?

Comment: You may want to double-check your post again. You have quite a few typo's in there, regarding terminology. For example, the ISP's router... ??? and landlords AP???? they both are the landlords router. Honestly, your post, although I get what you want to say and it is correct, the wording makes it pretty confusing.

Comment: Finally got the wire and it's working so far as suggested. Thanks for all the help. Will report back after some more testing